# CSS positioning questions

Tags: jquery, css, html

[Here is a demonstration of my current project.](http://life-style-sports.com/project/)

The main problem I am experiencing is in relation to the main slider I have purchased on a marketplace and it's positioning: I wanted to achieve this effect of overlapping the navigation over the slider, which seems to work to a certain extend, however I am unable to click the actual bullets for each individual slide.

Also I have a problem in relation to the infobox (caption of each slide) which seems to be in different positions if I am on differnt computers (my notebook and my PC) - is there a way to fix this caption box so that it is in line with the logo?

Code of the slider:

```
<div id="full-width-slider" class="royalSlider heroSlider rsMinW">
  <div class="rsContent">
    <img class="rsImg" src="img/slider/1.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="infoBlock infoBlockLeftBlack rsABlock" data-fade-effect="" data-move-offset="10" data-move-effect="bottom" data-speed="200">
      <h4>This is an animated block, add any number of them to any type of slide</h4>
      <p>Put completely anything inside - text, images, inputs, links, buttons.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="rsContent">
    <img class="rsImg" src="img/slider/2.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="infoBlock infoBlockLeftBlack rsABlock" data-fade-effect="" data-move-offset="10" data-move-effect="bottom" data-speed="200">
      <h4>This is an animated block, add any number of them to any type of slide</h4>
      <p>Put completely anything inside - text, images, inputs, links, buttons.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your code here, so we can help fix it.

Comment: Hello Doorknob, thank you very much for fixing my post. Please kindly find the entire source-code of my project here: http://life-style-sports.com/project/index.php

Comment: Yes, you showed that already, but you should post the specific code that you are having problems with here.

Comment: I have edited the post above and added the part in relation to the slider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS, remove `z-index: 0;` on `#full-width-slider` (line 83 style.css) - that fixes for me via dev tools.

An alternate solution (one that doesn't require your digging into source order and the stacking issues) would be to decrease the height on the over-stacked `#header` section element, and then apply `margin-bottom` to make the bullets accessible from underneath (you might need to tweak the actual values below):

```
    #header {
    height: 450px;
    max-height: 450px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
```

Hope that does it!

Comment: Hello - thanks for your message. I have tried that method earlier and it enables the slide controls, however the navigation disappears upon slide change.

Comment: In that case, it's down to a combination of positioning / z-indexing / and source order. Your slider is placed outside of and before the remaining markup's wrapper. The layout stacking needs to be modified with each component's z-index considered given the rules outlined here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index

Comment: Added the solution in answer :)